# Twitter OAuth is not working for embedded Godaddy websites

Tags: oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I have embedded my site in Godaddy and implemented the Oauth2.0. When I click on my login button it redirects me for the App approval and after approval I get access token. Using this access token I am able to get user data at the first time but suddenly the Iframe reloads itself and it sends the request again to get the access token while the same code is already being used to get access token that’s why I am getting below error:

**invalid_request: Value passed for the authorization code was invalid.**

However this issue arises only with Godaddy sites. Normal Iframe and without Iframe it is working fine.
I am unable to find why it’s reload the Iframe again in Godaddy.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you resolve this? Can you show us your code?